# fetching compact version of JSONB in PostgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql, jsonb

How to fetch compact `JSONB` from `PostgreSQL`?

All I got when fetching is with spaces:

```
 SELECT data FROM a_table WHERE id = 1; -- data is JSONB column

 {"unique": "bla bla", "foo": {"bar": {"in ...
^          ^          ^      ^       ^ --> spaces
```

What I want is:

```
{"unique":"bla bla","foo":{"bar":{"in ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`json_strip_nulls()` does exactly what you're looking for:

```sql
SELECT json_build_object('a', 1);
```

returns

```
{"a" : 1}
```

But

```sql
SELECT json_strip_nulls(json_build_object('a', 1));
```

returns

```
{"a":1}
```

This function not only strips nulls as indicated by its function name and as [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), but incidentally also strips insignificant whitespace. The latter is not explicitly documented in PostgreSQL manual.

Tested in PostgreSQL 11.3, but probably works with earlier versions too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [discussion, started in **2016**, about a function `jsonb_compact()`](https://postgrespro.com/list/id/CAH7T-ap6R_xzWz98c6AQzQuGsK_vpgr-et4VRaSjgxqom--ibw@mail.gmail.com) that will solve the problem... But, it could take years (!).

### Pretty solution

(a real solution for this question and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62323991/287948))

We must to agree with the PostgreSQL's convention for `CAST(var_jsonb AS text)`. When you need another cast convention, for example to debug or human-readable output, the built-in `jsonb_pretty()` function is a good choice.

Unfortunately PostgreSQL not offers other choices, like the compact  one. So, you can overload `jsonb_pretty()` with a `compact` option:

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION jsonb_pretty(
  jsonb,            -- input
  compact boolean   -- true for compact format
) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN $2=true THEN json_strip_nulls($1::json)::text
    ELSE  jsonb_pretty($1)
  END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT jsonb_pretty(  jsonb_build_object('a',1, 'bla','bla bla'), true );
-- results  {"a":1,"bla":"bla bla"}
```

### Rationale

- The JSON standard, [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2) says *"... Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters"*. In other words, the cast from `jsonb` datatype to `text` has no [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form#Computing). The PostgreSQL cast convention (using spaces) **is arbitrary**.
- **A lot of applications need** to minimize a big JSONb output. Two typical ones: minimizing file size of a big JSONb saved by `pg_file_write()`;  output online in a REST interface.
- The PostgreSQL team must to appreciate a real CAST procedure, not a parser, but a direct text production from JSONb internal representation.

  - The workaround — to remove spaces from "JSON text" — is not a  simple task, it need a good parser to avoid tampering content.  The solution **is a parser**, it is **not** a [regular expression workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325104/287948)... And **in nowadays** the built-in parser is `json_strip_nulls()`, even as "incidential behavior" parser.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonb` is rendered in a standardized format on output. You would have to use `json` instead to preserve insignificant white space. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-json.html)

> Because the `json` type stores an exact copy of the input text, it will
> preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens, as
> well as the order of keys within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON object
> within the value contains the same key more than once, all the
> key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last
> value as the operative one.) By contrast, `jsonb` does not preserve
> white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not
> keep duplicate object keys.

The whitespace really shouldn't matter for JSON values.

Comment: I still want all jsonb features, but I only want to compact the result.. maybe I should `parse` and `stringify` those result on the server side..

Comment: OP is asking if there's a way for postgres to produce results _without_ unnecessary whitespace, presumably to be sent over the wire. Parse/stringify introduces a bunch of extra processing.

Comment: @povman: If you store a valid JSON string as data type `json` in Postgres, the form is preserved *as is*  - including a valid form *without any insignificant whitespace*. Text representation of `jsonb` is rendered in a standardized form with a certain amount of insignificant whitespace. You would have to hack the source code and recompile to remove that. Or you need a function that is smart enough to remove insignificant white space from the text representation. The task is not trivial, though, I wouldn't know of any, doesn't mean there isn't one out there.

Comment: @Peter: I do *not* advocate to rely on `json_strip_nulls()` to strip insignificant whitespace. This behavior is incidential, not documented and may change or go away. A dedicated function for the purpose may be added to future Postgres versions, discussion is ongoing ...