# Convert JSONB to minified (no spaces) String

Tags: json, string, postgresql, select, jsonb

If I convert a text value like `{"a":"b"}` to JSONB and then back to text a space () is added between the `:` and the `"`.

```
psql=> select '{"a":"b"}'::jsonb::text;
    text    
------------
 {"a": "b"}
(1 row)
```

How can I convert a text to a jsonb, so I can use jsonb functions, and back to text to store it?

Comment: Why do you think the space is a problem? And why do you want to store the JSON value as `text` and not as `jsonb`?

Comment: Table already exists with lots o data, it's a generic column so there are values that are not json, migrating is not an option. I want to remove the spaces because that's how it is at the moment, I don't want to change behavior and also to save space

Comment: Then why convert it to json at all? Just store `'{"a":"b"}'` directly without converting it

Comment: Like I said, I want to use json functions to alter the data before storing it, something like `update table set text_colunm = (text_colunm::jsonb || '{"key":"newValues"}' - 'keyToRemove')::text`

Comment: so what's the problem with the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-json.html

"Because the json type stores an exact copy of the input text, it will preserve semantically-insignificant white space between tokens, as well as the order of keys within JSON objects. Also, if a JSON object within the value contains the same key more than once, all the key/value pairs are kept. (The processing functions consider the last value as the operative one.) By contrast, jsonb does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys. If duplicate keys are specified in the input, only the last value is kept."

So:

```
create table json_test(fld_json json, fld_jsonb jsonb);
insert into json_test values('{"a":"b"}', '{"a":"b"}');
 select * from json_test ;
 fld_json  | fld_jsonb  
-----------+------------
 {"a":"b"} | {"a": "b"}
(1 row)
```

If you want to maintain your white space or lack of it use json. Otherwise you will get a pretty print version on output with jsonb. You can json functions/operators on json type though not the jsonb operators/functions. More detail here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

Modifying your example:

```
select '{"a":"b"}'::json::text;
   text    
-----------
 {"a":"b"}
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON standard, [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2), says *"... Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters"*. In other words, the cast from `jsonb`  to `text` has no universal [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form#Computing). The PostgreSQL cast convention (using spaces) **is arbitrary**.

So, we must to agree with the PostgreSQL's convention for `CAST(var_jsonb AS text)`. When you need another cast convention, for example to debug or human-readable output, the built-in `jsonb_pretty()` function is a good choice.

Unfortunately PostgreSQL not offers other choices, like the compact  one. So, you can overload `jsonb_pretty()` with a `compact` option:

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION jsonb_pretty(
  jsonb,            -- input
  compact boolean   -- true for compact format
) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN $2=true THEN json_strip_nulls($1::json)::text
    ELSE  jsonb_pretty($1)
  END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT jsonb_pretty(  jsonb_build_object('a',1, 'bla','bla bla'), true );
-- results  {"a":1,"bla":"bla bla"}
```

See a complete discussion at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27505181/287948).

Answer (score 0):

The way your question and comments are phrased, it really looks like you want `replace()`.

We need to make the search as specific as possible to avoid messing with potentially embedded `': '` within the json payload, so it seems safer to match on the surrounding double quotes too, like:

```
replace('{"a":"b"}'::jsonb::text, '": "', '":"')
```

Comment: Indeed this could work for most of the cases but I'm afraid there might be occurences of `'": "'` within the json values. I was hoping to find some json function to solve this since after the conversion to text there's no way to tell what's part of the value and whats part of the json format